# Flutter; Type "null" is not sybtype of type List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter

Flutter writes Type "null" is not subtype of type List. What could be the problem? Everything works properly on the emulator in debug mode.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMddf.jpg)

```
      FutureBuilder indicatorRow(Goals goals, int goalMoney) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: DBHelper.instance.readAllAmountContributions(goals.id!),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var contributions = (snapshot.data as List) as List<Contributions>;
            return Column(children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 15,
                      width: 300,
                      child: LinearPercentIndicator(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 94,
                        animation: true,
                        lineHeight: 13.0,
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE9EBF1),
                        animationDuration: 2000,
                        center: Text(
                            '${((countContribution(contributions) / goalMoney) * 100).toStringAsFixed(3)} %',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 13)),
                        percent: (countContribution(contributions) / goalMoney)
                            .abs(),
                        restartAnimation: true,
                        linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
                        progressColor: const Color(0xFF442BEB),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
              underIndicatorRow(countContribution(contributions).toString(),
                  NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(int.parse(goals.amount)))
            ]);
          } 
        });
  }
```

Comment: you can try with this `(snapshot?.data??[] as List) as List<Contributions>;`

Comment: After you go with @JahidulIslam answer, try print 'snapshot' value on console after the if statement to check if the variable is really with some values.

Comment: @JahidulIslam Unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: what was the error

Comment: try add this `AsyncSnapshot` to builder  to be like this `builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) `

Comment: @JahidulIslam list<dynamic> is not a subtype of list<contributions>

Comment: After pop, I call setstate, which should update everything and get data from the database. It does it wrong, although everything is fine on the emulator(

Comment: Try to remove as list … and check the null on the snap data

Comment: The application works correctly in debug mode on the phone, however, when building the project and installing the apk, the application breaks (probably does not load the database, or loads incorrectly). What can be done about it?